# Extract book name from a string in Hive

Tags: regex, split, hive

My data is something like this -

```
1124 An Orphan's Journey
234 Red Dragon
35600 You'll Know When It's Time
```

It has two values, the first one is Book ID, and the second one is the book name.
I used the split function in Hive but that doesn't look proper.

```
SELECT split(books, '\\ ')[0] book_id,
split(books, '\\ ')[1] +  ' ' + 
split(books, '\\ ')[2] +  ' ' + 
split(books, '\\ ')[3] + ' ' + 
split(books, '\\ ')[4] as book_name
FROM books;
```

So far values are good but I don't feel it is the right approach.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(books, '^\\d+', 0)
```

to get the book ID and

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(books, '\\s+(\\S.*)', 1)
```

to extract the book name. The second regex can be more verbose, say, you may also check if there are digits at the start of the string before, `'^\\d+\\s+(\\S.*)'`.

Here,

- `^\d+` - matches one or more (`+`) digits at the start of the string (`^`)
- `\s+(\S.*)` - matches one or more whitespace chars (`\s+`) and then captures into Group 1 any non-whitespace char (`\S`) and then the rest of the string (`.*` matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible). Note the *index* argument is set to `1` in the second callt o `REGEXP_EXTRACT` to make sure the Group 1 value is only returned, without the initial whitespace.

Comment: I used 
````
select REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, '^\\d+') from books;
````
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract@15a9caeb of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with arguments {1124 An Orphan's Journey:java.lang.String, ^\d+:java.lang.String} of size 2

Comment: @Onlydocs Try setting the index argument to `0`, `REGEXP_EXTRACT(books, '^\\d+', 0)`

Comment: Added 0 as specified. It's returning the book numbers only. I need the book's name. So I tried to change the index but it's returning me the IO error.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't see the second point you mentioned.
It's working.. Thanks..!!